# Getting error on rich panel java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlPanel.setReadOnly(boolean)

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

Getting error on rich panel

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlPanel.setReadOnly(boolean)

using richfaces 3.3.0 and jsf 1.2. Checked the latest version of richfaces also but the method is not found in it.

Comment: Well it looks like you're trying to use a non-existent method. Post the code that causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using **readonly="true"**
on  rich:panel tag  but **readonly** attribute is not available for rich:panel. More details on available attributes is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.1.GA/en/devguide/html/rich_panel.html)